# python execute if statement if value matches any elements of a list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I want to print elements of a `list` under a for loop one by one using an if statement.
here's what I did:

```
   list[4,15,17,18,19,23,30,31,32,33,38,39,48,49,52,54,55,56,66]
   for i in range(0,67):
        if i==any(list):
            print(i)
```

I only want the `if` statement to run if `i` equals to any one of the values inside the list which is  `[4,5,6,17,18,19,23,30,31,32,33,38,39,48,49,52,54,55,56,66]`

one can do it by writing multiple if statement like:

```
if i==4:
    print(i)
if i==15:
    print(i)
if i==17:
    print(i)
.......
if i==66:
    print(i)
```

Please let me how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Try `if i in list`

Comment: Why this range(0,```67)```? Your *list* has only *19* items.

Comment: so, I wanted to perform multiple sets of equations for different i values. These i values will come from a list which can be 0-67 or 0-900. These are actually some calibration stations. I wanted to set different equations for different sets of calibration stations. Because of the locations and types the equations will vary. I know you can tell me to use those list in seperate seperate for loops but I want to plot all the 66 or 500 stations in a chronological order. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if it is in range, for example:

```
alist = [4, 15, 17, 18, 19, 23, 30, 31, 32, 33, 38, 39, 48, 49, 52, 54, 55, 56, 66]

r = range(0, 67)

for i in alist:
    if i in r:
        print(i)
```

Through I'm  not sure why you need this, can you share some details?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the below code.

```
temp_list = [4,15,17,18,19,23,30,31,32,33,38,39,48,49,52,54,55,56,66]
for i in range(0,67):
    if i in temp_list:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Because I wanted to use an else statement for all other values that are not in temp_list for which I wanted to use a different equation to implement.  Thanks. rdas already answered the question in his comment, so I can't accept anyone elses answere other than upvoting rdas's  comment.

Comment: You could explain what's your expected output, and why range(0, ```67```)  it's not clear what's your goal.